# [Error: MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly: state = START]

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug, multipartform-data

i receive this error when i try to send a form

```
link(rel='stylesheet',href='/stylesheets/home/profile/home_menu.css')
script(type='text/javascript',src='/javascripts/perfil_editar.js')

#logo_usuario
    img(src='')
#nombre_usuario(class='titulo1') 
    input(type='text',placeholder='',id="perfil_inputdatos_usuario")
    input(type="text",placeholder="",id="perfil_inputdatos_tipo")
#datos_fondo
#perfil_publicaciones_fondo
    select(id='perfil_publicaciones_lista',size='2')
        option(value='si', selected='selected') Publicacion 1
        option(value='no') Publicacion 2
    #perfil_publicaciones_ir
        t Ir    

#perfil_busquedas_fondo
    select(id='perfil_busquedas_lista',size='2')
        option(value='si', selected='selected') Busqueda 1
        option(value='no') Busqueda 2
    #perfil_busquedas_ir
        t Ir    


#ubicacion_fondo

#datos_usuario
    #perfil_datos_nombre
        img(src='/images/logo_nombre2.png')     
    #perfil_datos_telefonos
        img(src='/images/logo_telefono2.png')   
    #perfil_datos_direccion
        img(src='/images/logo_direccion2.png')
    #perfil_datos_mail  
        img(src='/images/logo_web2.png')

    form(action='/nuevaEdicion',method='post',enctype='multipart/form-data',id='editar')
        input(type='name',name='perfil_inputdatos_nombre',id='perfil_inputdatos_nombre')
        input(type='name',name='perfil_inputdatos_direccion',id='perfil_inputdatos_direccion')
        input(type='name',name='perfil_inputdatos_telprivado', id='perfil_inputdatos_telprivado')
        input(type='name',name='perfil_inputdatos_telcontacto',id='perfil_inputdatos_telcontacto')
        input(type='name',name='perfil_inputdatos_telcelular',id='perfil_inputdatos_telcelular')
        input(type='name',name='perfil_inputdatos_mail',id='perfil_inputdatos_mail')

#datos_titulo(class='titulo2')
    t Datos

#perfil_publicaciones_titulo(class='titulo2')
    t Publicaciones Realizadas
#perfil_busquedas_titulo(class='titulo2')
    t Busquedas Guardadas

#ubicacion_titulo(class='titulo2')
    t Ubicacion
#perfil_editar
    t Editar Perfil
```

i render this with this script in ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.perfil_nav a').click(function(){
      var objAttr=$(this).attr("id");
      $('#informacion').animate({height:'hide'},600,
        function()
            {
              $.ajax({
                url: "/profile_arquitecture_/"+objAttr,
              }).done(
                function(msg) {$('#informacion').html(msg);});
            });
        $('#informacion').fadeIn(600);
    });

});
```

only change one div named informacion from this file
home.jade

```
extends layout

append head
    link(rel='stylesheet',href='/stylesheets/home/home.css')
    script(type="text/javascript",src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=es")
    script(type='text/javascript',src='/javascripts/home_menu.js')

block contenido_central
    #contenido
        #capa_principal
            #barra_sesion
                #barra_menu
                    ul(class='perfil_nav')
                        li(class='first') 
                            a(href='#',id='miperfil') Perfil
                        li 
                            a(href='#',id='mispublicaciones') Mis Publicaciones
                        li 
                            a(href='#',id='misbusquedas') Mis Busquedas     
                        li(class='last') 
                            a(href='#',id='mismensajes') Mensajes
            #informacion
```

appending the form.jade in the informacion div
in the routes.perfil.js it renders with res.render

```
exports.editarPerfil=function(req,res)
{
    console.log(req.body)   
    res.render('home/nosotros',
    {title: 'Bienvenido ',
     sessionUser: req.session.passport.user
    });
}
```

in the app.js

```
app.post('/nuevaEdicion',express.bodyParser(),routes.perfil.editarPerfil);
```

this is the error in console

```
[Error: MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly: state = START]
{}
```

EDIT 2:

i discover that when i put in form

```
enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

the page freeze but when i put

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

i have to click many times in submit but the form works properly and the result in console is

```
{ perfil_inputdatos_nombre: '',
  perfil_inputdatos_direccion: '',
  perfil_inputdatos_telprivado: '',
  perfil_inputdatos_telcontacto: '',
  perfil_inputdatos_telcelular: '',
  perfil_inputdatos_mail: '' }
```

when i put

```
enctype="text/plain"
```

the form works properly fine fast and no problem but the result in console is

```
{}
```

so i think the problem is in html but any can solve this??? tanx

this is the profile id handler

```
exports.profile_pages=function(req,res)
{
    var usuario_actual=req.session.passport.user;
    mongo.dbusuarios.infoUsuario(usuario_actual,function(err,items)
    {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render('home/profile/home_'+req.params.id,
        {
            title:'',
            layout:false,
            datos_perfil:items,
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Look at the generated HTML for the form in your browser (after going back to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). Are there any surprises?

Comment: probably shout be the generated html but in source code does not apear... im trying to append the form in a div with ajax...

Comment: Then what does it look like if you fetch it with wget or curl or the like, or if you `console.log()` the results of the ajax request in the browser?

Comment: how can i console.log() the results of ajax??? in client or in server?? i think the problem is the browser... im still trying maybe this is an issue

Comment: In the browser; just make sure your JavaScript console is open (Firebug, Dragonfly, etc.) and then have the code that makes the AJAX request call `console.log` on the results.

Comment: "Resuming debugger: error during debugging loop: TypeError: firstViewRangeElement is null"

ReferenceError: data is not defined
[Interrumpir en este error]  

}

Comment: aparently there is no answer from the server... anyother idea???

Comment: Show the code around where you're rendering the form.

Comment: What's the code that handles a request for "/profile_arquitecture_/id" (i.e. what your AJAX call is requesting)?

Comment: i put the handler in lasts lines... tnx for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click handler should `return false` to keep the browser from trying to process the click. That may be what's messing you up. If that doesn't help, `console.log()` the value of `objAttr` and make sure there really is a jade file corresponding to its value.

Comment: yes that was one of many problems that i fix thanx to you bye